# Change background of disabled material fill input

Tags: css, angular-material

Using Angular Material I can change the background of this fill-matInput:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Tax-number</mat-label>
  <input type="text" matInput [id]="'taxnumber'" [formControl]="controlContainer.control.controls['taxnumber']">
  <mat-error>{{controlContainer.control.controls['taxnumber'].errors | bsErrorMessage}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I can change the background using the following css:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill
.mat-form-field-flex {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Now I want to change the background of the control when it is disabled. My best guess would be

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill:disabled
.mat-form-field-flex:disabled {
    background: rgba(255, 15, 15, 1);
}
```

But this does not work. So how do I change the background of a disabled angular material fill input instead?

I created a stackblitz for this problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcqsjo

Comment: I don't have an env for this but just looking at it, might they have used a disabled class? i.e., `.mat-form-field-flex.disabled`

Comment: nope - I created a stackblitz for repo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcqsjo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking out your stackblitz link I just opened up chrome dev tools and inspected the disabled field. Here is the css being applied:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-flex {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.02);
}
```

So there is an additional class (mat-form-field-disabled) on the parent. Your updated code would be:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill.mat-form-field-disabled .mat-form-field-flex {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```